# UITextView wrap text with cornerRadius?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, word-wrap

Is it possible to make the UITextView wrap its text within the cornerradius of the layer? If I have a textview with cornerradius half of the width, it makes a circle. If I want to display text in that circle, I would loose a lot of the text outside the circle.

Comment: This question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270997/how-to-draw-a-non-rectangle-uitextview

Comment: @Martol1ni Do you want the text to be editable?  If you just want to display text without letting the user edit it, you can use the answer in the question linked by titaniumdecoy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would be possible to achieve the desired effect, but not with a single UITextView, and it wouldn't be easy.  The word wrapping would have to be manual, segmenting the string into a series of UILabels that fit within the circle.  Perhaps you should reconsider the design - does reading a paragraph bounded by a circle really make sense?

Comment: Well, maybe I should reconsider the design. What I want, is to have dynamic text shown on an image of a circle on the screen. I have already started the manual wrapping, and it is NOT pretty..