# Wrapping Text in a UITextView Around a UIImage WITHOUT CoreText

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uitextview, word-wrap, nsattributedstring

Is there a way to wrap text from a `UITextView` around a `UIImage` without using `CoreText`?

I have been playing around with attributed strings without much luck, and `CoreText` just seems extremely complicated so I would rather stay out of it.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
UIBezierPath * imgRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
self.textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[imgRect];
```

Swift,

```
textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [UIBezierPath(...)]
```

or just

```
textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [UIBezierPath(...the image frame)]
```

Works only from iOS 7 and up.

Comment: @JoeBlow yes, just a normal UITextView. Thanks )

Comment: How to add image in that rect area

Comment: @deepakkumar I'd probably try adding your image view on top of UITextView at the needed location

Comment: Its possible on multiple images

Comment: I would vote this as the single best iOS answer on StackOverflow!

Comment: well explained in this article:https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/280-flowing-text-around-images-with-exclusion-paths

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4:

```
self.textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [UIBezierPath(rect: imageView.frame)]
```

Comment: I kind need to add a UIView(), I'm trying `let view = UIView()` and `[UIBezierPath(rect: view.frame)]`, got no error but still not working... any idea?

Comment: hmm.. has the view's frame been defined by the time this is being called? if using auto layout, you ma need to add this to `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()` (if in `UIViewControlelr`) or `override func layoutSubviews()` (if in `UIView`).

Comment: This is what I'm trying https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66026071/how-can-i-add-uiview-to-uitextview?noredirect=1#comment116740501_66026071

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't without CoreText pre iOS 7.

I've been struggling with this myself a while ago and [this post](https://robnapier.net/wrapping-text-around-shape-with-coretext) was very helpful to me.

It is CoreText though.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess I'll just have to figure out this CoreText stuff. Thanks.