# How could you make a uilabel wrap around an image (like shown)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring

How could you achieve this effect:[image]

Maybe some sort of NSAtributedString?

I have thought of hacky ways to just add spaces, but it needs to do it dynamically based on the width of the image.

Any ideas?

---

**NOTE** happily you can do this very easily with UITextView:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20033752/294884

this question is about UILabel.

Comment: Use a `UIWebView` and an HTML string/snippet instead?  That approach can be made to work similarly to an `NSAttributedString`, but is far more powerful and also less obtuse at the same time.

Comment: You might want to look into TextKit. From the Apple docs, "Using TextKit, you can lay out styled text into paragraphs, columns, and pages; you can flow text around arbitrary regions such as graphics"

Comment: What about using a UITextView and disable it? `(userInteractionEnabled = no)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473125/ios-swift-wrapping-text-around-image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216135/wrapping-text-in-a-uitextview-around-a-uiimage-without-coretext/20033752#20033752

Answer (score 8):

Add image in your label with text as below code:

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Here is some text that is wrapping around like an image"];

    NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
    textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first.jpg"];

    NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];

    [attributedString insertAttributedString:attrStringWithImage atIndex:0];

    [_lbn setAttributedText:attributedString];
```

Your **OUTPUT** :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `NSAttributedString` with an `NSTextAttachment`

```
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc]init];
[attachment setImage:<#UIImage#>];
NSAttributedString* icon = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];
[attributedString insertAttributedString:icon atIndex:<#index#>];
```

but it will only insert the image on one line, so it wont have multiple lines down the side of it (like a newspaper article), so its only useful for small images that fit on one line (sort of like how you have it in your question i guess)