# How do you format a text around an image

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on an Xamarin Forms project, and I need a `ContentPage` to display a few paragraphs, with an image.

I want to layout it out in a common way:

1. The image takes up the top left quarter of the screen
2. The text fills in the remaining three quarters.

How do I format my label to dynamically adjust to the image like that?

Comment: Have you tried StackLayout?

Comment: Yes, I have tried stacked layout. By default, that just puts the image above the text. I want the image to the left of the first few rows, but once the text passes the image, it should expand to fill the entire width of the view. The image should appear embedded in the text, across multiple lines. How can this be achieved?

Comment: stack layout should put text next to image. Can you paste your xaml ? Do you use vertical orientation?

Comment: You definitely can put text to the right of the image but to wrap it not sure about forms. It is possible in each platform. May be you need to implement that as View and create renderers in each platfrom.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248759/how-to-layout-text-to-flow-around-an-image and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082055/how-could-you-make-a-uilabel-wrap-around-an-image-like-shown

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a [Stack Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/stack-layout). This layout looks good and sorts quite well!

Best wishes