# Wrapping text around an image in Xamarin.Forms without WebView

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible place image in the top left corner and wrap text around it?

Like shown:

[image: Example image]

The best I can achieve is to put the image on the left and text on the right, but when the text is bigger it doesn't look good.

Comment: Take a look at [CSS styling with FlexLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout#css-styling-with-flexlayout) , if it does not help , you may need to implement this on specific platform with custom renderer ,Android : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248759/how-to-layout-text-to-flow-around-an-image ,iOS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082055/how-could-you-make-a-uilabel-wrap-around-an-image-like-shown.

Comment: I was looking at this  question and also have this problem , this you solved it ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't. I've added all the content inside webview.