# How to set UIView inside UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitextview

The below picture shows that there is a view Inside TextView. Now I want that Where UIView ends from there textview starts editing, not only from Left-top also from left-bottom.

> How to do it ?
>
> Is it possible ?
>
> If Yes, then how ?
>
> If no, then any other suggestion ?

**In case of text filed below code is applied for left padding**

```
UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
    textField.leftView = paddingView;
    textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

[image]

Comment: refer this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20033752/433562

Comment: Thank you @AnandV ... you just made my daye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can wrap textfiled using below code

```
UIBezierPath * imgRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
self.textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[imgRect];
```

> And, now you can add any control in place of "imgRect"

```
 UIView *spacerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
spacerView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; 
[textView addSubview:spacerView1];
```