# iOS how to insert UITextField inline within UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard

Is there a way to insert text inputs inline inside a block of text? I need to allow users to input some data inline within text. I thought that I would be able to use `NSMutableString` with attachments, but it seems to support only `UIImage` as attachments.

This is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You should take a closer look to _CoreText_ (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html) which gives you a very fine grained access to text layout. But anyway, this is a difficult task. You may create a HTML-Page with `input` fields and display it in a `WKWebView`, which should be much easier to implement.

Comment: you can try something like this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216135/wrapping-text-in-a-uitextview-around-a-uiimage-without-coretext

Comment: @macmoonshine Thank you for your suggestions! I tried the simpler approach with WKWebView and it worked out just fine for my case. If you copy your comment over to answer area, I'll be happy to mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a closer look to [CoreText](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html) which gives you a very fine grained access to text layout. But anyway, this is a difficult task. You may create a HTML-Page with `input` fields and display it in a `WKWebView`, which should be much easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If the text is static, create a custom `UIView` class, and position the `UILabel` and `UITextView` controls. This is the only possible approach.

If the text is dynamic, you can make use of Auto-layout concept along with the above approach.