# How can I add UIView to UITextView

Tags: swift

I'm trying to append a UIView inside a UITextView. Visually speaking it would be `some text, banner, more text`.

This is what I tried:

```
// does nothing
text.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [UIBezierPath(rect: view.frame)]
```

```
// works but it also removes the text
text.addSubview(view)
```

This is my class

```
class ViewController: BannerController {
    @IBOutlet weak var text: UITextView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {        
        let view = UIView()
        
        banners.append(view)
                        
        let myString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Text at the beginning\n")
                
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // text.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [UIBezierPath(rect: view.frame)]
        
        // text.addSubview(view)
        
        text.attributedText = myString
    }
}
```

I also saw this https://github.com/vlas-voloshin/SubviewAttachingTextView, but I couldn't figure it out how to apply to my code.

Is it even possible? I'm new at Swift and I have no idea what to do.

Comment: For library you mentioned "simply change the class of `UITextView` you use to `SubviewAttachingTextView`"

Comment: `text.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [UIBezierPath(rect: view.frame)]`, I guestt you wanted to use `view.bounds` instead of `view.frame`, but even here, your `view` has `.zero`. So it's unclear how you expected it to work.

Comment: @Larme, just changing to `.bounds` still the same. What does `.zero` means?

Comment: I meant `CGRect.zero`. `let view = UIView(); print("view frame: \(view.frame)`, so you applied the exclusion path to "nothing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use https://github.com/vlas-voloshin/SubviewAttachingTextView
Just follow below link:

https://github.com/vlas-voloshin/SubviewAttachingTextView/blob/master/Example.playground/Contents.swift

Comment: It took me some time, but worked. Thank you